# page.evaluate - how to write to file inside of it?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

How I can write result inside page.evaluate to file? This code works fine when putting results into console.log, but writing to file, using `ts` raising errors.

```
page.evaluate(function(url) {
        function getHTTPResponseString(url, callback) {
            try {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onload = function() {
                    if (this.status == 200) {
                        var u8 = new Uint8Array(this.response), bs = [];
                        for (var i = u8.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                            bs[i] = String.fromCharCode(u8[i]);
                        }
                        callback(bs.join(''));
                    } else {
                        console.log(this.statusText);
                        callback('');
                    }
                }
                xhr.open('GET', url, true);
                xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
                xhr.send();
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
            }
        }
        getHTTPResponseString(url, function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        })
    }, url);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that it's possible to pass data by calling `window.callphantom()` inside of `page.evaluate` and next handle passed data by `page.onCallback` event:

```
page.onCallback = function(result) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.write('file.out', result, 'w');
};


getHTTPResponseString(url, function(result) {
     console.log(result);
     window.callPhantom(result);
})
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks! Haven't come across this callback, it definitely seems very useful for extracting information from pages.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

One can't write to file from inside of page.evaluate() function, as it's working in browser context where there is no access to local filesystem.

However you can return data you want to analyze and then deal with it on PhantomJS side.

```
var error = page.evaluate(function(url) {
    // ...
    return xhr.statusText;
  }, url);

fs.write(filename, error, 'a');
```

Perhaps a simpler way to log data is to subscribe to console messages from browser context with [page.onConsoleMessage](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html) function:

```
page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) {
    console.log("Browser console: " + msg);    
};
```

There's also a **page.onError** function to listen for errors that happen inside **page.evaluate**: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html

Comment: Upvoted, but that's not what's I need. I found different solution, look at my answer.